# How can I programmatically detect segments of a data series to fit with different curves in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series data in which I want to fit particular equations, looking at the data it seems it should be segmented into three parts and fitting different equations in all parts. Is there any library in python which can find appropriate segmentation points in data to minimise overall error in fitting the three equations?

As in these pictures, data was manually divided into three parts and appropriate equations were fitted, I am looking for a function which can give the two most significant points on x-axis to divide the data in three parts.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNsLs.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BgdN.png)

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: I believe you want to detect structural breaks in your time series. Easiest way to detect breaks is to check for change in descriptive statistics across points. e.g. for each point define a window of say 10 period and calculate mean/variance for 10 period ahead and 10 period looking backwards. Points around which this difference is maximum represents structural breaks. There are many ways to detect structural breaks, but it all depends on time series. Just a query, why only 2 splits?

Comment: Chow test. You can find multiple implementation of it in various libraries